# How to clone the same object to three objects using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

Hi i get my JSON as an object in the below way:

```
    {
        "id": "001724",
        "select": false,
        "class": "product",
        "Names": [
          "A",
          "B",
          "C"
        ],
        "available": true,
        "description": "selected product",
        }
```

And i want to sort my JSON using Underscore.js in my javascript file, i'm trying to clone my main object to "names"  objects adding an atrribute "name"

```
[{
A:[
0:{
    "name":"A"
   "id": "001724",
   "select": false,
   "class": "product",
   "available": true,
   "description": "selected product"

}
]
B:[
0:{
    "name":"B"
   "id": "001724",
   "select": false,       
   "class": "product",
   "available": true,
   "description": "selected product"
}
]
C:[
0:{
   "name":"C"
   "id": "001724",
   "select": false,
   "class": "product",
   "available": true,
   "description": "selected product"
}
]
default:[
0:{
    "name":"B"
   "id": "001724",
   "select": false,       
   "class": "product",
   "available": true,
   "description": "selected product"
}
]
}]
```

and default array contains same as 'B' array

I'm trying to  to achieve this using underscore.js

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: yes sir, but i'm not able to get the desired output

Answer (score 1):

do you tried:

```
var newObj = _(obj).clone();
```

Comment: I tried cloning, but how can i add an extra attribute "name" for each object. Yes, we need to use _.clone here, but it doesn't gives the exact output i'm looking for

Comment: you can easily add it to the new object: `newObj.name = "something";`

Answer (score 0):

You can clone an Object in plain JavaScript using `Object.create`:

```
if(!Object.create){
  Object.create = function(o){
    function F(){}; F.prototype = o;
    return new F;
  }
}
var clone = Object.create(yourObjectHere);
var anotherClone = Object.create(yourObjectHere);
```

If you don't clone you're really referring to the original Object, even if the variables are different.